# How to get Repeated values Based on condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like below:

```
id     pid    status
10     1      0
11     1      0
10     2      0
15     1      0
11     2      0
10     3      0
```

I need the common `id` based on `pid` values. That means the `id` values that are common for all `pids`.

So in the above table the expected output is:

```
id    
10
```

I had tried below query but it does not work as expected:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM mytable COUNT(1)
FROM mytable
WHERE pid IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY checkpointid
```

Comment: I will never understand why people would call a non-unique column `id`. How is that and Id of anything if it's not unique?

Comment: @ZoharPeled this is not for testing purpose not the original one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Tbl
GROUP BY Id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Pid) = (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Pid)
  FROM Tbl
)
```